# XeLaTeX textsuperscript issue

Tags: fonts, xetex, superscripts

In XeLaTeX I have a `\textsuperscript` issue with all fonts I've tested, with regard to the dash. As opposed to what happens in LaTeX, in XeLaTeX the dash does not get superscripted.

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=Common,
  Numbers=OldStyle,
  ]{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}

88--100\textsuperscript{88--100}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: `xltxtra` loads `realscripts` package, that is the culprit. `realscripts` activates OpenType features for sub/superscripts, but most fonts have limited glyph coverage in those features and it seems to be the case with the font you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find that the problem disappears completely if you don't load the `xltxtra` package and add the instruction

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

to the preamble.

From page 4 of the `fontspec` manual:

> The `xltxtra` package adds some minor extra features to XELATEX, including,
>   via the `metalogo` package, the `\XeTeX` macro to typeset the XETEX logo. While this
>   package was previously recommended, it serves a much smaller role nowadays and generally
>   will not be required. Please consult its documentation to assess whether its features are
>   warranted before loading it.

In short, you may not need the `xltxtra` package at all.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=Common,
  Numbers=OldStyle,]{Minion Pro}
\begin{document}
88--100 \textsuperscript{88--100}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I hadn't noticed `xltxtra`. Good catch!

Comment: @NVaughan - The key to solving the problem was the fact that you posted a complete MWE, as it showed exactly which packages you were loading.

Answer (score 1):

I used the MWE, just replacing "Minion Pro" with "Arial" and the problem dissappears.

Removing xltxtra requires to add fontspec.  According to the xltxtra package manual, it loads "fixltx2e, metalogo, xunicode and fontspec". I tried fontspec with every package loaded by xltxtra, one by one and the problem does not present. If I add xltxtra instead, the problem presents again.

Therefore, the problem is associated with xltxtra.

But, if you use xltxtra without fontspec, *and use a different font*, for instance "Arial" or "Times New Roman", the problem does not present.

What call my attention is that I don't have installed "Minion Pro", but the MWE is compilable by XeLaTeX. Therefore, I must conclude that the problem is specific to xltxtra and with how "setmainfont" manages "Minion Pro" or its absence.

I should add that on second reading of the manual (Section 2.1), if you use "\usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}" in the MWE, the problem disappears.