# textsuperscript and hash symbol

Tags: horizontal-alignment

How can I get a text superscript of the hash (#) symbol in Latex to work? I tried `\textsuperscript{\#}` to no avail.

I should have been more specific in my question. I am using `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\usepackage{xltxtra}`, with `\setmainfont{Calibri}`. While Latex/Xelatex prints the #, it does not print it as superscript. When I use fonts Arial, Computer Modern, or Palatino, Latex correctly prints the # as superscript.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\begin{document}
\textsuperscript{\#}example
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you seen this? [Escape character in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34580/escape-character-in-latex)

Comment: Didn't see this before, but also note that you've mistyped `\textsuperscript`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit. Also, we usually don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: `\textsuperscript{\#}`works fine.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: If you would like for the question to be reopened, it would be helpful if you to post a complete minimal (non)-working example, rather than just saying which packages you are using.

Comment: The reason for the problem seems to be package xlxtra. It redefines the macro \textsuperscript. While this does not affect all fonts, it affects font Calibri. A work-around is to use the original definition with the starred command, i.e. \textsuperscript*{\#}

Answer (score 2):

Reread Sean Allred's comment:

```
\textsuperscript{\#}
```

Note: \tex **t** superscript...

If you are using `xltextra` with a font which does not support real super/subscripts, then you can tell it not to use them as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132910/39222) by djnavas:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}
\usepackage{microtype}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\begin{document}
\textsuperscript{\#}example
\end{document}
```

Comment: This previous post seems to be closely related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132884/xelatex-textsuperscript-issue

Comment: @user47979 So it is a duplicate of a different question? But this was only obvious now you've posted an MWE.